# Installing octave on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, octave

My instance is running on a 64bit Amazon Linux(Red Hat).

Following the instructions here:
http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_GNU/Linux, I run

> $sudo yum install octave

which yields the following result:

> No package octave3.2 available.

When I try

> $sudo rpm -Uvh http://dowload.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

I get

> package epel-release-6-7.8.amzn1.noarch (which is newer than epel-release-5-4.norach) is already installed.

Does anyone successfully installed octave on Amazon EC2? How should I proceed?

Comment: what does `yum search octave` returns?

Comment: amzn-main      | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates   | 2.3 kB     00:00     
Warning: No matches found for: octave
No Matches found

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable extended packages.  Try `yum search octave --enablerepo=epel` (I tested, it works :), or just enabling epel globally, as specified here: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#epel.